# Unbungling my dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

So I have a Rails app, that Rails App is running on Ruby 2.3.3, and I have then bundled a local gem (gem A) that contains an engine, that gem loads a library that is bundled with another local gem (gem B) that gem A depends on. However after upgrading the devise within gem B, and upgrading the Rails App to 5.0, gem A doesn't seem to be able to find devise from within gem B.

Any thoughts on best approach to go about debugging this? Or where I may have gone wrong?

Comment: you can version  your gems. So that if you update B and it breaks A, you can add a version for gem B in the gemfile and revert to an old version of the gem.

Comment: It's possible that A requires an older version of Devise. Can you update the A dependency to a newer version that doesn't have that restriction?

Comment: Have you tried `bundle update`?

Comment: @TomAranda yeh, stepping through gem by gem now! Don't know why I hadn't done that earlier!

Answer (score 0):

Try running `bundle update` in your terminal.